# Error at startup "No module named 'six'"

Tags: python, 17.04, crash, anaconda

I am running Ubuntu 17.04 and for some time now, every time I start my machine I get an error about the `package-data-downloader` that crashed because of `No module named 'six'`. See this screenshot:
[image]

I am wondering if it might have something to do with my Python3.6 and Anaconda installs. When I run `python -V && which python` I get:

```
Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda, Inc.
/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python
```

So when I saw that the `InterpreterPath` was pointing to python3.5, I wondered if it might be related.

If anyone can help me out it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

'six' is a python package that allow to run Python2 code with Python3 runtime (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six). The error message seems to indicate that your system is missing the package.

It would be nice to have the opinion of someone with more expertise, but I would do `sudo apt install python3-six` and see if the error disappear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but if six was really missing, it shouldn't show up when I do pip list right? Because it shows me six (1.11.0) when I run the pip list command

Comment: Could be that `six` is installed for python2 but not for python3. If output of `pip --version` says Python 2 this could be it. Also just try `python3 -c "import six"` and see if there's an error.

Comment: I rand the `pip --version` command, it outputs `pip 9.0.1 from /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)`. Also, the command `python3 -c "import six"` gave no error